# Optimizing spherical mask shader for mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, shader

I have used a shader that is very heavy for mobile performance. Can someone help me to improve it in order to get better performance?

I have noticed that my FPS with this shader goes from 60 to 30.

```
Shader "Custom/Sphered2"
{Properties
{
  [HDR] _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)

    _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _ColorStrength("Color Strenth", Range(1,4)) = 1

    _EmissionColor ("_EmissionColor Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _EmissionTex ("_EmissionColor (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _EmissionStrength("_EmissionColor Strenth", Range(0,4)) = 1

    _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
//    _position ("World Position", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
  //  _Radius ("Sphere Radius", Range(0,100)) = 0
    //_Softness("Sphere Softness", Range(0,100)) = 0
}
SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex,_EmissionTex;

    struct Input
    {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
        float2 uv_EmissionTex;
        float3 worldPos;
    };

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
     fixed4 _Color,_EmissionColor;
    half _ColorStrength,_EmissionStrength;

  uniform     float4 GLOBALmask_position2;
uniform    half GLOBALmask_Radius2;
uniform    half  GLOBALmask_Softness;
    // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
    // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        // put more per-instance properties here
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
    {
        // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        half grayscale = (c.r + c.g + c.b) * 0.333;
        fixed3 cgg = fixed3(grayscale,grayscale,grayscale);

fixed4 e = tex2D (_EmissionTex, IN.uv_EmissionTex) * _EmissionColor *_EmissionStrength;

        half d = distance(GLOBALmask_position2,IN.worldPos);
        half sum = saturate((d - GLOBALmask_Radius2)/ -GLOBALmask_Softness);
        fixed4 lerpColor = lerp(fixed4(cgg,1),c * _ColorStrength,sum);
        fixed4 lerpEmission = lerp(fixed4(0,0,0,0),e,sum);

        o.Albedo =c.rgb;
        // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Emission = lerpEmission.rgb;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
  }
```

I have used it like this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RayCastMovePos : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform playerTransform;
public float radius2,sm;
public Vector4 myPos2;

void Update()
{
    myPos2= new Vector4 ( playerTransform.position.x , 
playerTransform.position.y, playerTransform.position.z, 0); 

    //radius =Mathf .Clamp ( ( myVisualizer.allRythem 
[0]+myVisualizer.allRythem [1]+myVisualizer.allRythem [2]) * 170,2,1000);
//  radius2 =Mathf .Clamp ( ( myVisualizer.allRythem 
[3]+myVisualizer.allRythem [4]+myVisualizer.allRythem [5]) * 150,2,1000);

    Shader.SetGlobalVector    ("GLOBALmask_position2", myPos2);

    Shader.SetGlobalFloat  ("GLOBALmask_Radius2", radius2);
    Shader.SetGlobalFloat  ("GLOBALmask_Softness", sm );


   }
 }
```

I am new to shaders, but if there are any suggestions for glowing a sprite, I would be glad to hear it.

Comment: For optimizations, I think you have a higher chance of success over at [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: One simple optimization to try can be found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.PropertyToID.html Get the ID for the shader property in Start() and then SetGlobalFloat(id). As the page notes, it is more efficient. I doubt it will have a massive impact though.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a sprite, then do you really need to use a surface shader? These include tons of overhead, like lightmapping support, shadow casting/receiving, forward light support, etc. I'm sure a vertex/fragment shader would work fine for your purposes. You get emission by simply adding extra color to the final output.

Here is how the body of Unity's sprite shader looks:

https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/CGIncludes/UnitySprites.cginc

Comment: It is so helpful, You are right, I will use vertex/fragment shader